# Private and Public IP Address

Tags: ip

How can i determine a private and public IP Address.
For ex. I have bin given an IP address 190.168.1.254 is this a private or public IP address.
Please explain in the comments below.

Comment: What did you do to find the answer to this question?  I have no knowledge about IP addresses, but it took me less then a minute to query Google and find the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is the private ip address ranges:

10.0.0.0 – 10.255.255.255,

172.16.0.0 – 172.31.255.255,

192.168.0.0 – 192.168.255.255

if any ip isn't in this ranges so it's a public ip
190.168.1.254 is a public ip because it starts with 190 and there's no private ip range start with 190